# Animator not taking effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a simple script attached to a game object, I have the following:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;

    void Awake()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        if (!animator)
        {
            Debug.Log("NO animator!");
        }        
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the `NO animator!` message. What am I missing?

Comment: Silly comment, but did you attach [the Animator component](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html)?

Comment: I have attached an `Animator` component, though no animator controller. Do I need an animator controller?

Comment: I've posted the answer. Please let me know whether it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you!  I marked it as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I found an answer [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TargetMatching.html) - you should apply `[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]` to the `Test` class:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly the answer to the problem. In a comment the OP claims to have attached an Animator component. The attribute makes sure the component is attached to the same game object and cannot be removed. Problem is that if the animator is meant to be on another object, then you have two of them and the wrong one is used. So yes, it fixes since now the error is gone, but maybe now the problem is elsewhere now.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for your comment. I made sure it was attached to the right object.